# Правильные пути для ресурсов локализации

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Есть решение с тремя проектами:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`NameThatTitle.WebApp` - непосредственно проект ASP.Net Core

В классе `Startup` настройка папки для ресурсов локализации задана так: 
 `services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Localizations");`

Есть класс `NameThatTitle.Domain.Services.AccountService` для которого я использую соответствующий локализатор: `private readonly IStringLocalizer<AccountService> _localizer;`

Пробовал размещать соответствующий ему файл ресурсов и прямо в корне папки реcурсов с полным именем `NameThatTitle.Domain.Services.AccountService.ru.resx` и формировать путь вместо точек `NameThatTitle/Domain/Services/AccountService.ru.resx`, но почему-то перевод не подхватывается из файлов ресурсов.

Похожая проблема с пустым классом заглушкой `NameThatTitle.WebApp.Infrastructure.SharedResource`, который я размещаю в `Infrastructure/SharedResource.ru.resx`. (Использую для `IdentityErrorDescriber`).

Причём `DataAnnotation` у классов во `NameThatTitle.WebApp.ViewModels` нормально подхватываются из `ViewModels/<ClassName>.ru.resx`

Также, судя по [исходному коду](https://github.com/aspnet/Localization/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Localization/ResourceManagerStringLocalizer.cs) локализатора, он использует логер, но у себя в логах я не вижу никаких записей, связанных с локализацией =(